# Unable to populate recycler view using Retrofit and RxJava2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am trying to fetch data from server and showing it in recycler view.I am using retrofit library and RxJava2 but its unable to fetch data from server.It is showing total count in LogCat but not showing data in recycler view.

Response from the server:

```
[
 {
  "term_id": "4",
  "name": "Entertainment"
 },
 {
  "term_id": "5",
  "name": "Tech &amp; Gadgets"
 },
 {
  "term_id": "6",
  "name": "Sports"
 },
 {
  "term_id": "7",
  "name": "Health and Fitness Tips"
 }
]
```

Below is my code:

**RetrofitClient.java**

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getInstance(){


OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(22,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();

if(retrofit == null)
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://www.flypped.com/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

return retrofit;

   }
 }
```

**ApiService.class**

```
public interface ApiService {

@GET("Categoery_api")
Observable<List<Model>> getData();
}
```

**Model.java**

```
public class Model {

@SerializedName("catId")
@Expose
String catId;

@SerializedName("catName")
@Expose
String catName;

public Model(){

}

public Model(String catId, String catName) {
this.catId = catId;
this.catName = catName;
}

public String getCatId() {
return catId;
}

public void setCatId(String catId) {
this.catId = catId;
}

public String getCatName() {
return catName;
}

public void setCatName(String catName) {
this.catName = catName;
}

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recycler;
ProgressBar progress;

List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();;
PostAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progress = findViewById(R.id.progress);
    recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    fetchData();
}

private void fetchData(){

Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
ApiService myApi = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

 myApi.getData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                       .subscribe(new Observer<List<Model>>() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                           }

                                           @Override
                                           public void onNext(List<Model> models) {

                                               if(models.size() > 0){

                                                   progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                                   Log.d("count",String.valueOf(models.size())); 
                                                  adapter = new PostAdapter(getApplicationContext(),list);
                                                   recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                                               }
                                           }

                                           @Override
                                           public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                           }

                                           @Override
                                           public void onComplete() {


                                           }
                                       });

                       }
```

**PostAdapter.java**

```
 public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {

 List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
 Context context;

 public PostAdapter(Context context,List<Model> list) {
   this.context = context;
   this.list = list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public PostAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_row,parent,false);

ViewHolder view = new ViewHolder(v);
return view;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

Model model = list.get(position);

holder.catName.setText(model.getCatName());
holder.catId.setText(model.getCatId());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView catId,catName,comp,titl;

public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    catId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.catId);
    catName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.catName);
  }
 }
}
```

Someone please let me know why data is not showing in recycler view.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: One possibility that you might forget to set `LayoutManager` to recycler view ..

Comment: I have updated my answer and added layout manager but still data is not showing .

Comment: Just Use `adapter = new PostAdapter(getApplicationContext(),models)`. Cause `list` is always Empty ..

Comment: @ADM oh, well spotted...I missed that one was `models` and one was `list`.  This is definitely the problem, removed my previous suggestion.

Comment: After replacing list with models  it is still showing empty.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create adapter in `onCrete` method of `MainActivity`. Then add into your adapter a method

```
public void setItems(List<Model> data){
    list.clear()
    list.addAll(data)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

And use this method to add items into adapter.

```
myApi.getData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                   .subscribe(new Observer<List<Model>>() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                       }

                                       @Override
                                       public void onNext(List<Model> models) {

                                           if(models.size() > 0){

                                               progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                               Log.d("count",String.valueOf(models.size())); 
                                              adapter.setItems(models)
                                           }
                                       }

                                       @Override
                                       public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                       }

                                       @Override
                                       public void onComplete() {


                                       }
                                   });

                   }
```

Update your MainActivity method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progress = findViewById(R.id.progress);
    recycler = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new PostAdapter(this, new ArrayList());
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

    fetchData();
}
```

Comment: could you please tell  me where do I place above method in my existing code

Comment: where do I add setItems() method because if I am adding it in MainActivity then it is not showing up with adapter.setItems().

Comment: add it into PostAdapter class

Comment: On doing so Its saying `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.apitest.PostAdapter.setItems(java.util.List)' on a null object reference`